# Why did Bonnie think he'll never understand?

Tags: doctor-who

In The Zygon Inversion, the Doctor tries to convince Bonnie not to hit the Osgood Box to start a war. Then she says

> You don't understand. You will never understand.

Then he says he does understand, and goes on to say:

> I mean, do you call this a war? This funny little thing? This is not a war! I fought in a bigger war than you will ever know. I did worse things than you could ever imagine. And when I close my eyes I hear more screams than anyone could ever be able to count! And do you know what you do with all that pain? Shall I tell you where you put it? You hold it tight till it burns your hand, and you say this. No one else will ever have to live like this. No one else will have to feel this pain. Not on my watch!

Why did Bonnie think he'll never understand? Is it because she thought he wouldn't understand what is like to be in a war?

(And is the bigger war he fought in the Time War?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Because she doesn't know him, or because she lacks experience

Zygon Clara believes that UNIT won't let her walk free after her various crimes.

> CLARA-Z: No! I'm not stopping this, Doctor. I started it. I will not
>   stop it. You think they'll let me go, after what I've done?

But it's more than that. She thinks she can't stop something this big, once she  has started it. 
She thinks that the Doctor doesn't really understand the stakes involved, or perhaps the emotional investment she has in this conflict. She thinks she had gone too far to back out. The Doctor believes that this is because of her inexperience.

> DOCTOR: You're all the same, you screaming kids. You know that? Look
>   at me, I'm unforgivable. Well, here's the unforeseeable. I forgive
>   you. After all you've done, I forgive you.

The Doctor, on the other hand, has been in a very nearly analogous situation, which he arguably handled much better than Zygon Clara. At the very precipice, he turned back. Thus he knows that Zygon Clara can as well.

> CLARA-Z: I don't understand how you could just forgive me.
>
> DOCTOR: Because I've been where you have. There was another box. I was
>   going to press another button. I was going to wipe out all of my own
>   kind, man, woman and child. I was so sure I was right.
>
> CLARA-Z: What happened?
>
> DOCTOR: The same thing that happened to you. I let Clara Oswald get
>   inside my head. Trust me. She doesn't leave.

Comment: how does the war doctor pressing the moment with 10th and 11th doctor simmiler to bonnie pressing the Osgood box

Comment: @AndrewCasali - Because it was not relevant? Besides, those people are *all him*.

Comment: @AndrewCasali The other doctors didn't help him press it. They helped him NOT press it. Besides, how would you explain that one to someone not well versed in time travel?

Comment: what would bonnie think if he said he had help deciding to press the moment from his other selves 10th and 11th doctor

Comment: dosent matter if there the same person he could of said he had help pressing the moment

Comment: it thought it have been been important to say i thought him saying he had help from his other selves would of been cool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39048/discussion-between-jonah-and-andrew-casali).